# How can I change the logical URI of my web service?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis

I have a WCF service running under IIS7.  It can be accessed just fine at http://myserver.domain.com/myservice.svc

I don't want to change the physical location or name of this file but I want calls to http://myserver.domain.com/this/here to be handled by http://myserver.domain.com/myservice.svc

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - with .NET 4 you can quite easily - with .NET 3.5, it's possible, but more work.

In .NET 4, you could use file-less activation which allows you to define a logical URL in web.config - no more need for a *.svc file. But in this case, you cannot use the "old" URL with the *.svc file anymore (since there is no SVC file anymore).

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment>
      <serviceActivations>
        <add relativeAddress="this/here" service="IYourService"/>
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Read all about this and other new WCF 4 features at [A Developer's Introduction to WCF 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354381.aspx)

For .NET 3.5, there's only the way of rewriting your URL's - a rather thorny way to go - read more about it in the [MSDN library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx) or see Scott Guthrie's [blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx) on it.

Comment: I felt like there had to be a way to do this using WCF in .NET 3.5  Now that I know there isn't I started looking at other options like URL Rewriting.  We ended up going with the URL Rewrite Module for IIS7.  It seems to be working now.  Thanks for your help.